# Why i can't use request.getParameter in my form

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

i have a question about using `request.getParameter()`, i knew that it can use to post the value using request.getParameter, Is it necessary match `request.getParameter` and `<input>`???

My original code in HTML:

```
<INPUT type=submit name="submit" value="download">
```

In JSP:

```
String start = request.getParameter("submit");
```

Now I want to change a button and use div

```
div name="submit"id="submit" class="btnStyleFunc"
onclick="document.body.style.cursor='wait';this.disabled='true';
document.getElementById('form').submit();">
```

But it doesn't work, anyone can help me ?

---

Now i use the method below, but another problem is raised...the action does not stop...

```
String start = request.getParameter("submit1");

<input type=hidden name=submit1 value=download>
<div class="btnStyleFunc" onclick="document.body.style.cursor='wait';
this.disabled='true';document.getElementById('form').submit();">
```

Does anyone know what the problem is ?

Comment: post some codes what you've tried so far

Comment: `request.getParameter()` is JAVA, you say you wrote JSP and you tagged JavaScript...

Comment: better explain your scenario why you need this situation in the first place , makes no sense to me

Comment: because i want to change the submit button

Answer (score 1):

A clicked submit button is a successful form control and its name/value pair will be submitted to the server in the form data.

If you submit a form with JavaScript, there is no clicked submit button, so it won't appear in the data. A `div` cannot have a `name` and is not a form control anyway — it isn't a submit button, even if it triggers JavaScript that submits the form.

Using a div with JavaScript also breaks the form for:

- Anyone not using a mouse/trackpad/etc to navigate the page (a div won't get the focus when tabbing through interactive elements)
- Anyone with JavaScript disabled
- Anyone using a screen reader in forms mode (div elements are not form controls).

Use a real submit button instead.